# Swift Compiler Error 'iostream' not found

Tags: c++, xcode, swift, iostream

I've tried to implement a project which I've found on github.

https://github.com/hossamghareeb/Facebook-POP-Tutorial

While I was implementing the .h and .m files I've got an error which was saying XCode could not find my 'iostream' file.

I'm working in SWIFT, using bridging-headers to use the framework. When I try to build the original project it works, but mine always fails.

[image]

How can I add my iostream file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those files are Objective C++, not Objective C. I don't think swift bridging works with Objective C++ headers.

Comment: Is there any chance that i could import those objective C++ files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift bridging does not support Objective C++ files. This means that any headers that consume or expose C++ entites (like `std::vector`; `std::iostream`) cannot be added to the bridging header.

The POP bridging header contains:

```
#import "POP.h"
```

You should really only `#import` that file in your own bridging header, rather than trying to `#import` all the `.h` files.

If you need to consume some of the API that's defined in `.mm` files that isn't exposed with an Objective C or plain C header, then you'll have to make your own header file that exposes it (and probably a back-end that implements what you've exposed).

The reason why you can use `.mm` files in a library that's being used by Swift is because all swift uses is the interface to those files - i.e. the `.h` files, and as long as those files are in plain C or Objective C, then you can make use of the code that is implemented in the `.mm` file. The `.mm` files are compiled by Objective C++ compiler (`clang++`)

Comment: Thanks, after a lot of cursing and DuckDuckGoing your answer was the one that actually made me understand why I couldn't use Objective-C++ headers (because they imported C++ headers) in my case.